# Retrieving Youtube video metadata using Javascript / HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, metadata

How to retrieve Youtube video metadata using Javascript/HTML5? 
Kindly share some links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=<video ID>&fields=items/snippet/title,items/snippet/description&key=<API key>");
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                 // console.log("Description:", response.items[0].snippet.description);
               //  var text = response.items[0].snippet.description;
                   var text = "Find me at sand also at fgdyh  thrj hrtyrt fhrtgh";
                   var html = findUrls(text);
                   function findUrls(text) {
                     var source = (text || '').toString();
                     var urlArray = [];
                     var url;
                     var matchArray;
                    // Regular expression to find FTP, HTTP(S) and email URLs.
                     var regexToken = /(((ftp|https?):\/\/)[\-\w@:%_\+.~#?,&\/\/=]+)|((mailto:)?[_.\w-]+@([\w][\w\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3})/g;
                    // Iterate through any URLs in the text.
                     while ((matchArray = regexToken.exec(source)) !== null) {
                        var token = matchArray[0];
                        urlArray.push(token);
                    }
```